# When to use MessageQueueTransaction for simple cases?

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, msmq

I'm new to MSMQ and trying to understand when to use MessageQueueTransaction class.  For example, is there any value to create a simple transaction just for putting a message in the MSMQ queue like this?

```
  using (MessageQueueTransaction t = new MessageQueueTransaction())
  {
     t.Begin();
     Message m = new Message(myString, formatter);
     queue.Send(m, t);
     t.Commit();
  }
```

I can't think of any and am tempted to reduce this code to....

```
     Message m = new Message(myString, formatter);
     queue.Send(m, t);
```

Am I losing anything?  Any chance this is going to end up in a partially sent corrupted state?

-MSMQnfused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is fine, since you only have a single step

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending one message at a time, you do not need to worry about maintaining message ordering or something like that, so your code is fine. You may still want to use a transaction on the `Receive()` side so that the message goes back on the queue if an exception occurs.

But MSMQ also allows you to express succinctly that there is just one message in this transaction:

```
queue.Send(m, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
```